# Normal/Bump/Color created in Substance Painter doesn't appear correct in rendered model material

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, shaders, normals

I created this

[image: https://i.imgur.com/2iHGVOT.png]

material in substance designer and generated the normal map, bump map, and color map and imported it into blender with a node setup like such

[image]

(note that I've tried both "Color" and "non-color data" with no difference between the two).

However, I end up with this in the render (zoomed in for detail):

[image]

Note that the handle part on the bottom left is lacking a material, and the entirety of the rest of the cup has the material applied. I've noticed that the noise shown is just an artefact of the default render I've set up.

As well, this is further strange because the material shown in the material viewer looks quite alright

[image]

Before you ask, yes I have quadruple checked that the material is applied.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Does your mesh have UVs?

Comment: @JtheNinja Nope, that was the problem. Thanks man.

Comment: please use the tools from this site to upload images so that they appear as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I hadn't created a UV unwrap of my model, and thus the texture/heightmap/normal map wasn't being applied.